# Apache hadoop Installation on Windows 10

Tags: apache, hadoop, windows-10, hadoop2

While setting up a single node cluster without Cygwin on windows 10,I followed the specific document- [Link for Hadoop installation in windows 10](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~shantas/Install_Hadoop-2.6.0_on_Windows10.pdf)

I am facing the below error while starting the hdfs using `D:\hadoop-2.6.2.tar\hadoop-2.6.2\hadoop-2.6.2\sbin>start-dfs.cmd`

Error message stack trace:

```
17/01/12 12:25:42 FATAL datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file permissions : ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515:
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:808)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1097)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.mkdirsWithExistsAndPermissionCheck(DiskChecker.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode$DataNodeDiskChecker.checkDir(DataNode.java:2299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2462)

    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:620)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.mkdirsWithExistsAndPermissionCheck(DiskChecker.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode$DataNodeDiskChecker.checkDir(DataNode.java:2299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations(DataNode.java:2341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2462) 17/01/12 12:25:42 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Also this error message about starting namenode:

```
17/01/12 12:25:43 FATAL namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canWrite(FileUtil.java:996)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:309)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1022)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:741)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:748)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1441)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1507)
17/01/12 12:25:43 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Comment: Did you pass through the above error `Error while running command to get file permissions` ?

Answer (score 0):

[]Problem analysis ]  /data directory permissions is not enough, the NameNode cannot be started.

[Solution]

(1) in the root, the operation of the/data/directory permissions assigned to hadoop users;

(2) empty /data directory file;

(3) to reformat the NameNode, restart the hadoop cluster.